# Looking for a 21 header pin 1.27mm

Tags: pins, header

[image: Header Pin]

I've been looking all over for days but there doesn't seem to be a header pin.

I'm looking for a 21 position header pin with a 1.27mm (0.050") pitch.
Can someone point me into the right direction.

Comment: Try looking for micro-D plugs, I'd guess that's the foot print of one of those connectors.

Comment: Is this a male header to solder onto a PCB? Or are you looking for a male connector that goes on a cable?

Comment: thanks ScienceGeyser will have a look.
@MarkLeavitt It's a male header through-hole or SMD doesn't matter. PCB to cable.

Comment: a zigzag *header*? is not a kind of connector? never seen anything like that

Comment: I don't think you'll find a header with that configuration. But you can get single-row headers with 1.27 mm (0.050 ") pitch in various longer lengths, and they can easily be snapped apart to get single 11 and 10 row headers. The PCB holes will ensure they are located correctly. But why? What connector is going to attach to it?

Comment: Yes did the same thing for now but it's not the best solution. I also had to remove a part of the sides to make the other row fit next to it. It's for an old iMac G4 LCD connector to make it HDMI compatible.